# Flutter Command - Powershell.exe not in PATH error message

Tags: flutter

I have flutter installed and everything works fairly alight but every time I run a flutter command I get the following message before the command actually runs.

Error: PowerShell executable not found.
Either pwsh.exe or PowerShell.exe must be in your PATH.

I added the Powershell.exe path to my PATH variable (both System & User) and also added C:\Windows\System32 as I read that on one of the Github/SO forums. Any idea how to get rid of this? I am following a Udemy course and have followed every instruction to the dot but the instructor does not get this message.

Comment: A restart of your terminal or your computer may help

Answer (score 7):

Go "Edit environment variables for your account" under "User variables" add to Path this line

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to user Path variables and system path variables

1. C:\src\flutter\bin

Add these to Environment System Path Variables

1. C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
2. C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
3. C:\Windows\System32

My problem was the missing of 3rd from System path variables.

Answer (score 2):

I have lost half a day to solve it and used all instructions on flutter site and and answers about powershell path. It didnt work until add C:\Windows\System32 to Path variable.

Answer (score 0):

copy the path, for my case, it is "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" and pastes it in environment variables as a path

Answer (score 0):

In case you encountered this problem and none of the above solutions worked for you. In my case, I set all the environment variables - I am using Windows 10. I even reinstalled flutter; but the problems persisted.

It turns out my Anti Virus had quarantined the Powershell executable file. I had to open the anti virus quarantine chest, restored the Powershell executable and restarted my VS Code.

Problems solved, after three days of searching for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `flutter upgrade` inside PowerShelL directory

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>flutter upgrade`